# Is Gill sans supported for export?

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with the data label font set as 'Gill sans'. However when i export the chart to png the font changes. Is Gill sans not supported for export? IE8 used.

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 0):

At this moment we cannot add extra font, but please request your idea on our uservoice website highcharts.uservoice.com.